# PL/SQL: How to enable all triggers in the schema?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I'm trying to make a procedure that uses a cursor that enables all triggers in my schema to be enabled. However, I'm getting this Error at line 16: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored which is the line that I use fetch for.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE enable_trigg_proc
   IS
    v_trigger_name trigger_name.user_triggers%TYPE;

    CURSOR enable_trigg_cur
    IS
    SELECT TRIGGER_NAME INTO v_trigger_name
    FROM user_triggers
    WHERE STATUS = 'DISABLED';


    BEGIN
     OPEN enable_trigg_cur;
    LOOP
     FETCH enable_trigg_cur INTO v_trigger_name ;
      EXIT WHEN enable_trigg_cur%NOTFOUND;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'ALTER TRIGGER v_trigger_name  ENABLE';
    END LOOP;
  close enable_trigg_cur;
END;
```

Comment: Explicit cursors cannot contain 'INTO' clause - that's why you get sql statement ignored issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need that much code:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select trigger_name from user_triggers) loop
  3      execute immediate 'alter trigger ' || cur_r.trigger_name || ' enable';
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

What's wrong with your code? `INTO` is required in PL/SQL's `SELECT` statement, but **not** within the cursor declaration. Also, you declared the variable in the wrong manner; should be

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE enable_trigg_proc
  2  IS
  3      CURSOR enable_trigg_cur
  4      IS
  5      SELECT TRIGGER_NAME
  6      FROM user_triggers
  7      WHERE STATUS = 'DISABLED';
  8
  9      v_trigger_name user_triggers.trigger_name%TYPE;
 10  BEGIN
 11      OPEN enable_trigg_cur;
 12      LOOP
 13        FETCH enable_trigg_cur INTO v_trigger_name ;
 14        EXIT WHEN enable_trigg_cur%NOTFOUND;
 15
 16        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'ALTER TRIGGER ' || v_trigger_name || ' ENABLE';
 17      END LOOP;
 18      close enable_trigg_cur;
 19  END;
 20  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec enable_trigg_proc;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I see my mistakes now. Thank you.